# After setting up dual-boot, Windows workspace not saved during sleep or hibernate

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, laptop, sleep, hibernate

I recently set up dual-boot (Ubuntu) on my Dell XPS 13 laptop. Before dual-booting, if my laptop was idle it would sleep and boot back up while saving my previous workspace (any tabs or documents would open as before).

Now if my laptop goes to sleep or hibernates, my workspace is lost and the computer fully resets. I have temporarily solved this problem by not allowing my laptop to sleep or hibernate but this has severely impacted battery life. I work almost entirely in Windows. I only occasionally use Ubuntu.

What did I do wrong, and how can I fix it to conserve my Windows workspace while my laptop enters sleep or hibernate?

Comment: Windows is notorious for not working well with multi-boot scenarios and hibernation/sleep. If you mainly use it, uninstall Ubuntu from the drive (and possibly reinstall/setup Windows). You can always create a Virtual Machine (VMWare, VirtualBox, etc) to install Ubuntu for those rare times you need it.

Answer (score 0):

> I work almost entirely in Windows. I only occasionally use Ubuntu.

If this is the case, set up Ubuntu as a Virtual Machine instead of Dual Boot and save yourself a lot of hassle.

I have done that here (both Kali and Ubuntu) and it works exceedingly well.

It is faster and more efficient and on a modern computer with an SSD, performance is very good.

You can then experiment with any other machine you might choose to use.

Comment: Hey John, 

If I did want to go through the hassle, is there a way you are aware of to make this work?

thanks for the reply.

Comment: I do not know any way of preventing Windows to restart in a dual boot scenario and that is why I suggest (in your case) virtual machines.  That is how I do what you are trying to do.

Comment: A virtual machine environment is a complete environment for testing other machines as well.